# PHP function to recursively apply a percentage to an amount

Tags: php, logic, mathematical-optimization

So I am trying to create a function that takes amount, percentage(decimal) and times and returns a double with the amount.

The result I expect is the following:

```
$amount = 10000
$percentage = 1.1
$times = 1
```

so..

```
elevateToPercentage($amount, $percentage, $times) = 10,000 * 1.1 = 11,000
$times = 2
elevateToPercentage($amount, $percentage, $times) = ((10,000 * 1.1) * 1.1) = 12,100
$times = 4
elevateToPercentage($amount, $percentage, $times) = ((((10,000 * 1.1) * 1.1) * 1.1) * 1.1) = 14,641

private function elevateToPercentage($amount, $percentage, $times) {
    $count  = 0;
    for( $a = 0; $a <= $times; $a++ ) {
        $count += ($amount * $percentage);
    }
    return $count;
}
```

I know this is a logic error but I´ve been up too much and I don't seem to work anymore right now :(
can you guys please help me out ?

Thank you!

Comment: `$a >= $times;` ?!? Surely you mean `<=`? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: @MarkBaker fixed the example. Thank you, see I am tired xD Still not doing what I need tho

Comment: What is `$count` for?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams To store the count of what is gotten from the operation in every loop.

Comment: I have no idea what you were trying to say there.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
function elevateToPercentage($amount, $percentage, $times) {
    if ($times == 1){
        return $amount * $percentage;
    }else{
        return $percentage * elevateToPercentage($amount, $percentage, $times -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good too bro! Thank you! I would like to mark both answers as correct.

Comment: Ravinder's answer is correct too, but if the goal was to use recursive functions, mine approach is better. If you don't need to use recursive approach (like if this wasn't homework "Use recursive functions..."), Ravinder's approach is probably more readable for majority of people.

Comment: Btw if it is homework, you should handle what will happen if $times < 1. See https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-recursion/ for additional info.

Comment: I understand recursion, just didn't figured out how to do this particular function. And no, this is not homework xD Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it using pow function

```
function elevateToPercentage($amount, $percentage, $times) {
    $multiple = pow($percentage, $times);
    return number_format($amount*$multiple) ;
}
$amount = 10000;
$percentage = 1.1;
$times = 1;
echo elevateToPercentage($amount, $percentage, $times);
```

Out put:

```
$times = 1; 11,000
$times = 2;  12,100
$times = 4; 14,641
```

Comment: That did it. I didn't know about this function. Thank you!